# Github can't find index.html in /src using webpack

Tags: html, github, webpack, host, src

I'm trying to host my website onto github through gh-pages but keep getting "If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the URL.
For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file."
Not sure what is wrong. I haven't had this problem when i host without using webpack but i gotta learn. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
[webpack setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na89u.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your `index.html` should be at the top level. Keep it outside `src` where you've your `webpack.config.js` file, this will help `gh-pages` to locate your index.html while deploying it.

Comment: that helped i guess i also needed to change the plugin within webpack.config.js on the plugins for the correct entry of the index.html. thank you!